# VS Code keyboard shortcut to only run selected line in .ipynb code cell

Tags: python, jupyter, visual-studio-code

I'm using the python extension for VS Code and I want to be able to just run the single line of the .ipynb code cell where the cursor is, not the whole code cell.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible as of now.

Comment: Here I made a feature request to run selection: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/200625 If you like it, please support by giving it a 